# Angular 4+ FormGroup returns INVALID if a FormControl is not present on the DOM

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a dynamic `formGroup` where sometimes it has radio buttons in it and sometimes checkboxes, and sometimes both of them (depends on the backend response).

Having :

```
   this.choiceForm = new FormGroup({
    selectedChoice: new FormControl('0', Validators.required),
    checkedBoxes: new FormControl(null, Validators.requiredTrue)
  });
```

the form group returns `INVALID` state if `selectedChoice` (radio buttons) or `checkedBoxes` (checkbox) if not any of them is not found on the DOM.

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to create your form only after it's confirmed what form control is needed according to response from backend.

A good example can be found at https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form.

```
// in controller

// get form data from backend
constructor(private service: MyService) {
    this.service.getForm().subscribe((response: any) => {
        if (response.data) {
            this.myForm = this.createForm(response.data);
        }
    })
}

// considering your data has following schema
[
    {
        key: 'key1'
        type: 'select'
        value: 'default' 
    },
    {
        key: 'key2'
        type: 'checkbox'
        value: true 
    }
]

createForm(data) {
    let group: any = {};

    data.forEach(item => {
        group[item.key] = new FormControl(item.value || '')
    })

    return new FormGroup(group);
}
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer? Possibly with a code example or a diagram?